# ASP.NET PostBacks and Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, fiddler

In Asp.net web forms, I click a button to submit a request. In the `Page_Load` method, `IsPostBack` is set to true and the button's `OnClick` handler is called.

However, if I capture that HTTP Post request (say in Fiddler) and resend it exactly, the `Page_Load` method says `IsPostBack` is false, and the button's `OnClick` handler is never called.

Why is this?

Edit:
Note that the method handler is actually decorated with

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
```

Comment: any luck? I tried this scenario and seems to be working just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may wanna check this out...

http://www.versomas.com/dannyg/post/Simulating-POST-with-Fiddler.aspx